# Twig form_errors function doesn't load translation message in validators.lang.yml

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm using Symfony2 translations in order to display error messages in my forms. My message is defined in `validators.fr.yml` located in the `Ressources/translations` subfolder of my bundle. I'm also using annotations to set the message to use.

**The problem is that the message is not shown in my template. I only get the key that i've defined in my annotation.**

A sample of code from my entity :

```
/**
 * Nom du site de travail.
 *
 * @var string le nom du site de travail.
 *
 * @ORM\Column(
 *      name   = "nom",
 *      type   = "string",
 *      length = 255
 * )
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "structure.siteTravail.nom.notnull")
 */
private $nom;
```

In my form class, I've implemented the `getDefaultOptions` method with the `data_class` option (don't really know if it helps) :

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'My\FreakingBundle\Entity\SiteTravail'
    );
}
```

Here is the content of `validators.fr.yml` :

```
structure:
    siteTravail:
        nom:
            notnull: Le nom est obligatoire.
```

In my Twig template I'm using this code to render the field's errors :

```
{{ form_errors(form.nom) }}
```

Also, translation is activated in `app/config/config.yml` :

```
framework:
    translator: { fallback: fr }
```

All my translations are working perfectly in `messages.fr.yml` for this bundle and I've got another bundle using both `messages.fr.yml` and `validators.fr.yml` as well.

The weirdest part is that when I put the content of `validators.fr.yml` in my other bundle, it works.

Comment: Translations files are loaded **only** in registered bundles. Have you registered your 2 bundles in your AppKernel ?

Comment: Anyway, the default place where validator messages are translated is here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L262 . Are you sure you didn't overrided one of the twig form blocks ?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the translation overriding the **field_errors** form block.

So, when you render the form in your twig template:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block field_errors %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        <ul>
            {% for error in errors %}
                <li>{{ error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators')|trans }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {# ... other stuffs ... #}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {# ... other stuffs ... #}
{% endblock %}
```

If you put the translations in a specific domain file (for example: "validators.lang.yml") use this syntax:

```
<li>{{ error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators')|trans({}, 'validators') }}</li>
```

Here you can find all the default form blocks for custom replacements purposes: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig